# Upload multiple images via website

Tags: images, uploading, photo-gallery

I have a requirement to allow the users to upload multiple images at once, like the way you upload photos to a photo printing website.  I am looking for suggestions as to what technology and which libraries that can be used to do this. I'm guessing Flash and JavaScript.

Comment: ...in some arbitrary way, or are you already using a CMS/framework that we should know about?

Comment: I am using codeigniter. I ended up using http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I have good experiences with [plUpload](http://www.plupload.com/), from the guys of TinyMCE. User experience is pretty good, considering my very non-technical user base.

If you consider paying, the MCImageManager is (IMO) a good choice (same guys).

Comment: I came here to say Plupload also.

Comment: +1 for Plupload.  It's being added to the next version of WordPress.

Comment: Plupload is good. Although I ended up using http://www.uploadify.com/ because it was easier to use with codeigniter (imho). Marking this as the answer because the two libraries are similar.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a very broad question so I'm afraid answers will be broad as well. Alot of technologies can handle this feature and there are different techniques including:

1. Have a single upload on the form and have the user upload a zip file which is extracted on the server (almost all server side technologies).
2. If you have a max amount of uploads, then have a form with that number of fields (again almost all technologies).
3. (MOST POPULAR) Use some client side technology like AJAX/Javascript or Flash to upload to the server.